# onCompletion not called while using Koltin Flow with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine, kotlin-flow

So here is what I was trying to do with `Flow`, I am showing a `ProgressBar` in `onStart` and trying to hide the `ProgressBar` in `onCompletion`.

**In ViewModel class** `appDatabase.eventDao().getAllEvents()` returns `Flow<List<EntityEvents>`

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val allEvents: LiveData<Outcome<List<Event>>> = _fetchEvents.switchMap { _ ->
    appDatabase.eventDao().getAllEvents()
        .map { eventListMapper.map(it) }
        .map { sortEventsBasedOnPreference(it) }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .map { Outcome.success(it) }
        .onStart { emitLoading(true) }
        .onCompletion { emitLoading(false) }
        .catch { emitFailure(it, R.string.err_something_wrong) }
        .asLiveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

All working fine, what I am not able to figure out why is `onCompletion` not called when the task is completed?

Comment: Don't you have to call a terminal operator to complete the flow? Or does it terminate automatically when it's out of items? "Terminal operators on the flow are either suspending functions such as collect, single, reduce, toList, etc. or launchIn operator that starts collection of the flow in the given scope."

Comment: It does terminate automatically and the data are loaded into UI, but shouldn't `onCompletion` get called when the `flow` completes. My objective was to show and hide `ProgressBar` in `onStart` and `onCompletion` operator respectively.

Comment: i ran through the same issue, how did you ended up managing it ?

Comment: I had the same issue but realized that the emitting part never completed and therefore onCompletion was never called. Check if your flow completes

Comment: @Hussain how did u solve the progressbar issue? i'm on the same boat

Answer (score 1):

if `appDatabase.eventDao().getAllEvents()` is based Room on Flow, never called `onCompletion()`.

**Why?**

Because `getAllXXX()` Query is 'Hot'.
Actually,  query is not completed. Only data is emited.

When the data changes, the query will emit data again.